# How to POST new nested entities using spring-data-rest

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-rest

just wondering if it is possible to POST new entities within new entities.

Person.java

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    @oneToOne(optional = false)
    private Address address;
}
```

Address.java

```
@Entity
public class Address {
    private String street;
}
```

What I would like to do is create a Person with an Address in one HTTP request. Is this possible with something like the request below?

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" /
-d '{"address": {"street":"street 1"}}' http://localhost:8080/people
```

So far my investigation and document searching says no. But thought I would ask here before giving up.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works, but in your example you haven't turned on cascading.

```
@OneToOne(optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Address address;
```

Furthermore you must not have an exported repository for `Address`. Otherwise `Address` and `Person` would be independent resources and had to be treated accordingly, which means separate POSTs.